# Override Stock Android Lockscreen

Tags: java, android, lockscreen, android-7.0-nougat

I want to know how to "override" the stock Android lockscreen to add a few things:

[image]

I want to add a text and the possiblity to swipe left or right to do something in my app.
But I would like to keep the stock android lockscreen.
How can I achieve that ? Should I create a custom lockscreen ? Can I just get the stock one and modify it ?

Thank you

Comment: There is no "stock android lockscreen". There are ~2 billion Android devices, spread across thousands of device models. There will be dozens, if not hundreds, of different lockscreen implementations from the device manufacturers.

Comment: The stock one from the Android nougat for example, I would like to start with something that is working well and just add a few things if possible

Comment: You would need to start with the lockscreen from your chosen custom ROM (e.g., LineageOS), where that custom ROM can be built for your chosen device(s).